# z-index issue in Chrome

Tags: html, css

i have a problem with setting z-index in Chrome, here my example http://dev.fama.net.pl/tides/index.html, click in the right triangle, new image should be above the letters and it is in all browsers except Chrome, all elements are positioned absolutely so it should works but it doesn't, anybody knows why ??

CSS

```
#central {
    color: #76b2d1;
    font-size: 22px;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -15px;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -215px;
    position: absolute;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    z-index: 0;
    font-family: 'gothic';
}
#container01 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 180px;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1;
}
#container02 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 55px;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 1;
}
#container03 {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 25px;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 1;
}
#container01 > div, #container02 > div , #container03 > div  {
    position: absolute;
    white-space: nowrap;
    font-family: 'gothic';
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
#p1text01 { 
    font-size: 41px;
    color: #f7ebd3;
    top: 0px;
    left: 50px;
}
#p1text02 {
    font-size: 26px;
    color: #f7ebd3;
    top: 55px;
    left: 245px;
}
#p1text03 {
    font-size: 75px;
    color: #f7ebd3;
    top: 55px;
    right: 80px;
}
#p1text04 {
    font-size: 28px;
    color: #f7ebd3;
    top: 145px;
    right: 365px;
}
#p1text05 {
    font-size: 160px;
    color: #f7ebd3;
    bottom: 40px;
    right: 100px;
}
#p1text06 {
    font-size: 36px;
    color: #f7ebd3;
    bottom: 35px;
    right: 200px;
}


#bg {
    position:fixed; 
    top:-50%; 
    left:-50%; 
    width:200%; 
    height:200%;
}
#bg img {
    position:absolute; 
    top:10px; 
    left:10px; 
    right:10px; 
    bottom:10px; 
    margin: auto; 
    min-width:50%;
    min-height:50%;
}
#bg img.blank {
    z-index: 0;
    display: none;
}
#bg img.pic {
    z-index: 2 !important;
    left: 20%;
    opacity: 0;
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)";
}
.arrow {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -120px;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    opacity:.2;
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=20)";
    cursor: pointer;
    border-top: 120px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 120px solid transparent;         
}
.arrow:hover {
    opacity:.5 !important;
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=50)" !important;
}
#arrow-left {
    border-left: 120px solid #83bedd;
    left: -125px;
    z-index: 3;
}
#arrow-right {
    border-right: 120px solid #83bedd;
    right: -15px;
    z-index: 3;
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="bg">
        <img class="blank" src="img/bg.jpg" alt="" data-xrange="20" data-yrange="20" />
        <img class="blank" src="img/bg.png" alt="" data-xrange="10" data-yrange="10"/>
        <img class="pic" src="img/bga.jpg" alt="" />
    </div>
    <div id="central">some text</div>
    <div id="container01">
        <div id="p1text01" data-xrange="30" data-yrange="10">some text</div>
        <div id="p1text02" data-xrange="10" data-yrange="10">some text</div>
    </div>
    <div id="container02">
        <div id="p1text03" data-xrange="40" data-yrange="10" data-invert="true">some text</div>
        <div id="p1text04" data-xrange="20" data-yrange="10" data-invert="true">some text</div>
    </div>
    <div id="container03">
        <div id="p1text05" data-xrange="50" data-yrange="10">some text</div>
        <div id="p1text06" data-xrange="25" data-yrange="10">some text</div>
    </div>  

    <div id="arrow-left" class="arrow"></div>
    <div id="arrow-right" class="arrow"></div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Switching the `position` of the `#bg` div from `fixed` to `relative` solves the issue, though I'm unsure if that will have a knock-on effect...

Comment: looks ok, i will test it with other browsers and let u know, thx

Answer (score 1):

`position:absolute` always goes on top of other types of position. I changed this for `#bg` in *Chrome's Dev Tools* and the image goes above the text.

Comment: i dont need #bg (parent) to be above texts, but #bg img.pic (one of the child) should be above the texts

Answer (score 0):

Try adding:

```
#bg {
     z-index: 2;
}
```

Comment: i dont need #bg (parent) to be above texts, but #bg img.pic (one of the child) should be above the texts

Answer (score 0):

`#bg {z-index: 2;}` seems to work. Not quite sure how this bug is happening though

Comment: i dont need #bg (parent) to be above texts, but #bg img.pic (one of the child) should be above the texts